# Spring Debug Logging in separate log file

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss7.x

Currently logging is performed with the below configuration in the standalone.xml. All the logs are now saved in server.log. I want to save the spring debug logs in separate file for debugging purpose.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new file handler which output to a different log file
- Set up desired categories having handler setting to the above one with use-parent-handlers="false".

Answer (score 0):

After lot of try, it worked with below configuration

Able to save the spring debug log in separate file and application log in another file (server.log).

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE_SPRING">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="SPRING">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="spring.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <rotate-size value="5480k"/>
                <max-backup-index value="3"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </size-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.springframework" use-parent-handlers="false">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="SPRING"/>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE_SPRING"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="spring-handler" autoflush="true">
  <formatter>
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="myapp.log"/>
  <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>







<logger category="org.springframework" use-parent-handlers="false">
  <handlers>
    <handler name="spring-handler"/>
  </handlers>
  <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```